# Find the development of a function $f(x)= x\cos^2(2x)$ in the power series in point $0$, and after that find derivative of $f^{(21)}(0)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I have to find the development of a function $f(x)= x\cos^2(2x)$ in the power series in point $0,$ and after that find derivative of $f^{(21)}(0)$

I have started with:\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{x(\cos(4x)+1)}{2}\\&=x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n*4x^{2n}+1}{(2n)!}\right)\\&=x\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{(-1)^n*4^{2n}*x^{2n}}{2(2n)!})+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n*4^{2n}*x^{2n+1}}{2(2n)!}+\frac{x}{2}\end{align}

And now I am not sure if I did it corectly, and if I did what to do next with this. Please help, I have spent 4 hours already with that exercise.

Comment: Why start with $14x$ inside $\cos$? If you meant $4$ instead of $14$ (that is, you used $\frac{\cos (2x)+1}{2}=\cos^2(x)$, so that you function became $x\frac{\cos (4x)+1}{2}$), then you're done. You just need to take $\frac{(-1)^n4^{2n}}{2(2n)!}x^{2n+1}$, which is $=f^{(2n+1)}(0)x^{2n+1}$, and consider $n$ so that ${2n+1}={21}$

Comment: You are right, there shouldn't be 14x inside cos, it was a mistake

Comment: Suggestion. If you write these series as with a few terms and then ellipses (...) rather than with the $\Sigma$ notation you won't have to worry about shifting indices to start at $0$ all the time, and can perhaps more easily see patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\cos(4x)&=\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x)\\&=2\cos^2(2x)-1,\end{align}and that therefore$$\cos^2(2x)=\frac12\bigl(1+\cos(4x)\bigr).$$So\begin{align}f(x)&=x\cos^2(2x)\\&=\frac x2\bigl(1+\cos(4x)\bigr)\\&=\frac x2+\frac x2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}(4x)^{2n}\\&=\frac x2+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n2^{4n-1}}{(2n)!}x^{2n+1}\end{align}and therefore$$\frac{f^{(21)}(0)}{21!}=\frac{2^{39}}{20!}.$$In other words, $f^{(21)}(0)=2^{39}\times21$.

Comment: I don't understand, how did you get 2^39, could you explain me please?

Comment: You have $2n+1=21\iff n=10$. And, if $n=10$, the coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$ is $\frac{2^{39}}{(20)!}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos x =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
$$f(x)=x\frac{1+\cos (4x)}{2} =\frac{1}{2}x +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n (4x)^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}$$
$$f^{(21)} (0) =21!\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{4^{21}}{20!}=42\cdot 4^{20}$$

Comment: I don't understand, how did you get 4^21/20, could you explain me please?